# Laravel resource return array element check against different model

Tags: laravel, collections, resources, contains

The subject of this question was a bit hard to formulate.
So i'll try to describe as detailed as possible my problem/question.

1 have 2 models.

1. Category
2. Product

On my product edit page i render a tree (jstree) with categories, for each category the product belongsTo the node of the tree needs to be checked.

My current approach is in the categoryResource i check if the category id belongs to the product, but this (of course) returns in a lot of queries as per category a query is fired to determine if the category belongs to the product.

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    // got a product id?
    if (request('product_id')) {
        $categories = Product::findOrFail(request('product_id'))->categories->pluck('id');
    }
    return [
        'checked' => !is_null($categories) && $categories->contains($this->id)
    ];
}
```

Other solution would be to load product categories in the controller and loop rebuild the 'resource' but this just doesn't feel right and also i need to be build recursive stuff (for child categegories) which Resource model can already handle.

Anyone got a more proper and solid solution?

If more information is required i'm happy to oblige :)

Comment: What output `toArray($request)` function will return if `product_id` exist?

Comment: `is_null($categories)` you did not define `$categories` variable?

Comment: The return of the toArray is

```lang-php
return [
'id' => $this->id,
'text' => $this->name,
'state' => [
'opened' => true, //($this->id === 1) ? true : false, //    : boolean  // is the node open
'checked' => !is_null($categories) && $categories->contains($this->id)
],
'children' => CatalogCategoriesJsTreeResource::collection($this->childs)
]
```

Comment: Don't seem to get the formatting correctly :( sorryr